# In Laravel after i store my data's in db redirect to the message api url. After i reach the url i need to get back to index page

Tags: laravel-9

After I press the submit button, it stores my data in my database and redirects me to the What's App. The API URL sends a message to the customer and shows the JSON result on the page.

My request is that after it sends a message, I reach the JSON view page, and in a few seconds, it is redirected to my index page.

Comment: You should be specifying what is it that you want to achieve better. start from telling us what are you trying to do, what's the problem, and what have you tried and what's the result. it will help the community to better understand your problem and maybe provide the best answer to your problem.